# How to set https proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, http2

How on earth do I use an https proxy with http2 in nodejs. I've tried looking around and I can't find any info on it. Take for example the following code:

```
const client = http2.connect('https://twitter.com');
const req = client.request({':method': 'GET', ':path': '/', ':authority': 'twitter.com', ':scheme': 'https', 'Cookie': loadCookies(cookiejar) });
req.setEncoding("utf8");
var body = "";
req.on('response', (responseHeaders) => {
storeCookies(responseHeaders, cookiejar);
});

req.on('data', (chunk) => {
    body += chunk;
});
req.on('end', () =>{ 

    client.destroy();
});
```

So how would I go about routing this request through a proxy, say for example Charles where the proxy would be set 127.0.0.1:8888.

Comment: Did you succeed ?